# Understanding the wikipedia entry on Dragon Curves

Tags: fractals

I'm playing around with Project Euler's [Problem 220](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=220), and I'm a little confused about the Wikipedia article on the topic, [Dragon Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve). On the topic of calculating the direction of the nth turn without having to draw the entire curve, it says:

> First, express n in the form k * 2^m where k is an odd number. The direction of the nth turn is determined by k mod 4 i.e. the remainder left when k is divided by 4. If k mod 4 is 1 then the nth turn is R; if k mod 4 is 3 then the nth turn is L.
>
> For example, to determine the direction of turn 76376:
>
> ```
> 76376 = 9547 x 8.
> 9547 = 2386x4 + 3
> so 9547 mod 4 = 3
> so turn 76376 is L
> ```

- Is there a clever way to figure out if n **can** be expressed as k2^m, apart from checking divisibility by successive powers of 2?
- What does it mean if n cannot be expressed in such a way?

(The problem involves calculating the position of a point on a Dragon curve with length 2^50, so actually drawing the curve is out of the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

m is the number of zero bits at the least significant end of the number.
The simplest algorithm is to divide by 2 as long as the number is even,
but you could also use binary search to speed it up.

All integers can be expressed in this way.

Comment: Would binary search speed it up? Faster than shifting, anding and branching?

Comment: You can organize your testing of least significant bits and shifting to be either by one bit at a time, or you could first do it for the lower half of the bits, then a quarter and so on, which is faster on modern machines.

Answer (score 1):

Any integer can be expressed as k * 2^m where k is odd.  To see why, write any number in binary.  Starting from the right (least significant bit), there will be a string of all zeros.  It might be an empty string.  The number of zeros is m.  The rest of the bits make up k.  k's least significant bit is a one (because if it were a zero, you'd simply extend your string of zeros), so k is odd.

To find k and m, you'll probably write a simple loop (Python in this case):

```
def k_and_m(n):
    k, m = n, 0
    while (k % 2) == 0:
        k >>= 1
        m += 1
    return k, m
```